# Reading from a text file to class objects (C++)

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding my code. I would like to obtain information from a text file and assign that information into class objects. I will use the information from objects later on to write a program.

My text file looks like this:

```
984763 A 20 18
762613 A 19 17
587123 A 22 16
897654 D 85 19
```

where the first columns represent ID#, Type, processing time 1, processing time 2.

This is my code:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <fstream>


using namespace std;

class trucks {
private:
    int ID;
    string Type;
    double feeder_pt;
    double axle_pt;

   public:
    void getID (int);
    void getType (string);
    void getfeeder (double);
    void getaxle (double);

};

void trucks::getID(int ID)
{}

void trucks::getType (string Type)
  {}

 void trucks::getfeeder (double feeder_pt)
 {}

 void trucks::getaxle (double axle_pt)
  {}

int main () 
{
ifstream myfile("sequence.txt");

int i=0;

int ID;

string Type;

double feeder_pt;

double axle_pt;

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {

    trucks truck[i];
    truck[i].getID(ID);
    truck[i].getType(Type);
    truck[i].getfeeder(feeder_pt);
    truck[i].getaxle(axle_pt);
    myfile>>ID>>feeder_pt>>axle_pt;

    }
// to test only

cout<< ID << endl;
cout<< axle_pt << endl;
cout<< Type << endl;
cout<< axle_pt << endl;
}
```

The output gives me the first element in the text file (984763) and nothing for the rest. It seems that the file is opening but there is something wrong with my code. Any help please?

Thank you,

Comment: What do you expect `truck[i].getID(ID);
    truck[i].getType(Type);
    truck[i].getfeeder(feeder_pt);
    truck[i].getaxle(axle_pt);` to do?

Comment: This is wrong `trucks truck[i];` because it declares a new container every time and how are you expecting to "get" values and your functions are just empty and do nothing?

Comment: There are too many problems here. This question cannot be salvaged. Pretty much everything that can go wrong here, does.

Comment: Possible duplicates:  [stackoverflow c++ read file struct](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+file+struct&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

When writing code, its important to understand what you are writing and why.
But here, let me give you an example:

Removed the extra TAB before each #include, for prettyness

Removed using namespace std, not needed.

Removed private:, class members are private by default.

Fixed class member casing, to make them consistent with each others.

Changed string type to char type, because it contains a single character.
Changed double to int, because the file contains whole numbers.
Changed signature of the getXX functions, if they are meant to "get" they should return a value and take no parameters.
Coded them inline, and they return the corresponding private member value.
Also renamed them to be consistent.
Added set functions, inline.

Renamed class trucks to Truck, since it represend one truck.

Declared variable trucks only once.

Removed int i=0; since it is already declared in the for loop;

changed i++ to ++i, its a tiny bit better.
Moved id, type, feeder_pt and axle_pt variable declaration to inside the loop.
Added type in "myfile >> ..." to read it as well

Removed duplicate "cout << axle_pt"
Added cout << feeder_pt
Added code to output the whole trucks array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Truck {
    int id;
    char type;
    int feeder_pt;
    int axle_pt;

public:
    int getID() { return id; }
    char getType() { return type; }
    int getFeeder() { return feeder_pt; }
    int getAxle() { return axle_pt; }
    void setID(int id) { this->id = id; }
    void setType(char type) { this->type = type; }
    void setFeeder(int feeder_pt) { this->feeder_pt = feeder_pt; }
    void setAxle(int axle_pt) { this->axle_pt = axle_pt; }
};

int main () 
{
    std::ifstream myfile("sequence.txt");

    Truck trucks[4];

    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        int id;
        char type;
        int feeder_pt;
        int axle_pt;

        myfile >> id >> type >> feeder_pt >> axle_pt;

        trucks[i].setID(id);
        trucks[i].setType(type);
        trucks[i].setFeeder(feeder_pt);
        trucks[i].setAxle(axle_pt);
    }

    // to test only
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
        std::cout << "ID: " << trucks[i].getID() << "\tType: " << trucks[i].getType() << "\tFeeder: " << trucks[i].getFeeder() << "\tAxle: " << trucks[i].getAxle() << std::endl;
}
```